# geckodriver 0.33.0 Firefox org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start new session Response 500 Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: java, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Facing the below error when trying to initialize Firefox driver.

Firefox version: 112.0 (64-bit)
Maven Dependency: io.github.bonigarcia > webdrivermanager version: 5.3.2
Gecko driver version: 0.33.0

Please find below the error message

```
main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Using geckodriver 0.33.0 (resolved driver for Firefox 112)
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.gecko.driver as C:\Users\subrav\.cache\selenium\geckodriver\win64\0.33.0\geckodriver.exe
      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED 

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAHqol1YAAAAAAAA...}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAHqol1YAAAAAAAA...}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:112)
```

And here is the code block which initializes firefox driver

```
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "true");
                System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "target/logs.txt");
                FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
                firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
                firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
                firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", file.getAbsolutePath());
                firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

I tried adding the below capability, preferences and add-arguments options but no luck

```
    firefoxOptions.setCapability("moz:debuggerAddress", false);
    firefoxOptions.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("fission.autoStart", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("fission.bfcacheInParent", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("fission.webContentIsolationStrategy",0);
    firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Could you please let me know what could be the issue and what can be done to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!!